# Why is there no response for the xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to access the feedzilla api. But when I do this there seems to be no response from the web service. What is it that went wrong? The following is my code.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="status"></div>
<script>

    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";   
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    var url = "http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/cultures.xml";
    hr.open("GET", url, true);    
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    hr.send();
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "sent...";
     hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "received...";
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at the network tab in the dev tools of whichever browser you may be using, that will give you more info about the request.

Comment: I did that too. The status just says pending and does not seem to change at all

Comment: My attempts at fetching `http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/cultures.xml` manually result in the connection timing out. Test your URLs manually, don't just run code and wonder why it doesn't work. You're trying to connect to a service that isn't responding.